# sort not sorting javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Only when I have the code in an on change event does the list become sorted. I want it to sort when the page loads. I have tried using onload but to no success.

Also I’m trying to make it so whatever the user selects, that value is the first one on the list.

Works…

```
myDropdown.onchange = function () {
         $("#dropdown").append($("#dropdown option").sort(function(a, b) {
                  return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
           }))
        myTextBox.value = this.value;
}
```

Doesn’t Work…

```
// var myDropdown = $('#dropdown');
// var opts_list = myDropdown.find('option');

// function sortTheList() {
//     $("#dropdown").append($("#dropdown option").sort(function(a, b) {
//         return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
//     }))
// };

// myDropdown.onload = function () {
//     $('#dropdown option').sort(function(a,b) { return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1; });
//     myDropdown.html('').append('#dropdown option');
// }
// myDropdown.onload = function () {
//     $("#dropdown").on($("#dropdown option").sort(function(a, b) {
//         return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
//     }))
// }
```

Comment: `myDropdown` is a jQuery object. It doesn't have an `onload`, but you can do `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757017/dropdown-javascript-onload?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of onload, try using onDOMContentLoaded.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded